# ajax form submit event attached twice

Tags: jquery, ajax, yii2

I have form over pop-up and to submit this form I have write custom code

form code over popup:

```
<div id="add-role" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div id="bank-details-form" >
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header card-header-text" data-background-color="rose">
                        <h4 class="card-title">Add Role</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="user-form  card-conten">
                        <div class="container-fluid">

                            <?php 
                            $roleModel = new \app\models\rolelist();
                            $form = ActiveForm::begin([
                                'layout' => 'horizontal',
                                'id' => 'role-form',
                                'enableClientValidation'=> false,
                                'fieldConfig' => [
                                    'options' => [
                                        'class' => 'form-group row',

                                    ],
                                    'horizontalCssClasses' => [
                                        'label' => 'col-sm-4 label-on-left',
                                        'offset' => 'col-sm-offset-4',
                                        'wrapper' => 'col-sm-6',
                                    ],
                                ],
                            ]); ?>
                            <div class="row form-group field-users-middel_name">

                                <?= $form->field($roleModel, 'role_name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
                                <?= $form->field($roleModel, 'status')->dropdownList(Yii::$app->params['status']) ?>

                                    <?= User::showLoader() ?>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <?= Html::submitButton('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-success center-block']) ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery code:

```
$('#role-form').submit(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
            var roleName = $("#rolelist-role_name").val();
            if(roleName != ""){
                $(".loader-div").css({display : 'block'});
                var data = $(this).serialize();
                $.ajax({
                    url : "<?= Url::toRoute('rolelist/createajax') ?>",
                    type : 'POST',
                    data : data,
                    success : function(responce){
                        $(".loader-div").css({display : 'none'});
                        var res = JSON.parse(responce);
                        if(res.result){
                            $("#user-role_id").append('<option value="'+res.data.id+'">'+res.data.role_name+'</option>')
                        }
                        $("#add-role").modal("hide");
                    }
                })
            }
        });
```

In inspect window I can see that there are two submit events attached with the form one is my custom event and another is attached by yii.activeForm.js

Any idea how to remove submit event attached by activeForm?

Comment: can you please confirm whether the form is submitted twice if `'validateOnSubmit'=> false'` is added to the form?

Comment: @AneesMuhammed yes, even when `'validateOnSubmit'=> false'`  is added to the form, form get submitted twice.

Comment: use an id for your custom button, and call submit event on it instead of form id, or you can do it by click event,

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are binding the submit like a normal form where as you are using Yii2 `ActiveForm` and it has its own events that you should use.

So in your case you should change the

```
$('#role-form').submit(function(event) {

});
```

to

```
$('#role-form').on('beforeSubmit', function(event) {

});
```

and dont forget to add the `return false` in the end inside of the event you are binding, your complete code should look like below

```
$('#role-form').on('beforeSubmit', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var roleName = $("#rolelist-role_name").val();
    if (roleName != "") {
        $(".loader-div").css({
            display: 'block'
        });
        var data = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url: "<?= Url::toRoute('rolelist/createajax') ?>",
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            success: function (responce) {
                $(".loader-div").css({
                    display: 'none'
                });
                var res = JSON.parse(responce);
                if (res.result) {
                    $("#user-role_id").append('<option value="' + res.data.id + '">' + res.data.role_name + '</option>')
                }
                $("#add-role").modal("hide");
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting `'validateOnSubmit' => false` for the ActiveForm worked for me.